# Oak Login Token Configuration

Tags: aem, jcr

I'm facing an issue in AEM6.1 were the users have an invalid login-token (due to having an expired session). They make a request to AEM author which then has an error because they are basically an anonymous user attempting to view a page. The access problem results in a 404. The ACS error page tries to handle it, but the error page like everything else on author is not readable to an anonymous user. So it has a Java exception, and the user is left with a white screen of death

The login-token cookies in the browser have no expiration. They appear to be configured to stick around until the session is closed by the users. I would like to set expiration on the login-token cookies.

I've research around but do not see how this is done. The aemstuff site http://www.aemstuff.com/#article964 points to "Apache Jackrabbit Oak TokenConfiguration"  But this was already set to 43200000, and further changes do not effect the login cookie expiration as far as I can see.

My question for SO is; is there a way to set the login-token expiration on the cookie? It seems like a bug with "Apache Jackrabbit Oak TokenConfiguration" or is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create Apache Jackrabbit Oak TokenConfiguration as a config node.

Answer (score 0):

In case others face similar problems, here some of the things I learned about this

- login-token expiration can be configured as suggested by disha. It is used on the backend only. I think its very typical for browser session cookies to not have an the expiry set.
- The WSOD issue experienced may have been helped by adjusting this session timeout slightly less than the IDP timeout
- I think it's very important to use Java 8 with AEM6.1 and perhaps other versions as well. When we upgraded from AEM6, Java 7 remained our running version. Possibly the SAML SSO uses Java 8 things. After going to Java 8, users never had the WSOD again.